# Is there a Sonar-Elixir plugin compatible with SonarQube 10.4.1?

Tags: sonarqube, elixir, sonarqube-plugin

I'm currently working with SonarQube version 10.4.1 and I'm interested in analyzing Elixir code within this environment. I've been searching for a compatible Sonar-Elixir plugin but haven't been able to find clear information.

Could anyone confirm if there's a Sonar-Elixir plugin available that works well with SonarQube 10.4.1? If so, could you provide details on where to find it and any steps needed for installation and configuration?

Additionally, if there are any known issues or considerations when using that plugin with SonarQube 10.4.1, I'd appreciate any insights or advice on how to address them.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one:

- https://github.com/adrienmo/credo_sonarqube

There is also an example of how to configure:

- https://github.com/adrienmo/credo_sonarqube/issues/1#issuecomment-760646572

and perhaps some adjustments:

- https://elixirforum.com/t/elixir-projects-in-sonarqube/15462/16